# Oracle Apex 23.1.2 : Alert message when interactive report returns 0

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have an interactive report that runs when the click a search button on certain criteria. When this interactive report refreshes, and returns 0 rows based on that search criteria, I want an alert to pop up that instructs the user that no entries were returned.

I have created a dynamic action that triggers each time the interactive report region refreshes, with the following javascript code:

```
var rowCount = $( '#RegionName .t-Body-content tr' ).length;

if (rowCount === 0 ) {
   alert( 'No entries found.' );
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't know. However - just asking - how come that built-in "Messages" IR attribute (that lets you specify what message to display when no rows have been found, or when far too many rows have been returned) isn't enough to alert users?

Comment: Sadly this wasn't deemed clear enough

Answer (score 0):

After a search, the "Selection Change [Interactive Grid]" event is fired, so you can put a dynamic action on that.

Here is how I got it to work:

Setup: An interactive grid with static id emp-ig. The name of the IG region is "IG alert when no records in search".

- **Dynamic Action** on event "Selection Change [Interactive Grid]".

[image]

- **True Action** of type "Alert" with the following settings. Note the client side condition.

[image]

Comment: This proved successful - thanks for the help